# symfony 6 json_login not working but admin login with form login is working

Tags: vue.js, symfony, symfony6

I have been trying to integrate json login for my user section which is VueJS axios based and form login for admin.

I have installed the EasyAdmin and form login for admin is working fine but the api based json login is not working at all.

Here sharing my security.yaml file

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
        App\Entity\Admin:
            algorithm: auto
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

providers:
    user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
    admin_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Admin
            property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    admin_secured_area:
        pattern:   ^/admin
        provider: admin_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: /admin/login
            check_path: /admin/login_check
            default_target_path: /admin/login
            username_parameter: email
            password_parameter: password
        entry_point: App\Security\AdminAuthenticator
        custom_authenticator:
            - App\Security\AdminAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: admin_logout
            target: /admin/login

    user_secured_area:
        pattern:   ^/api
        provider: user_provider
        json_login:
            check_path: user_login
        entry_point: App\Security\UserAuthenticator
        custom_authenticator:
            - App\Security\UserAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: user_logout
            target: /api/login

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/sign-up, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

when@test:
security:
password_hashers:
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
algorithm: auto
cost: 4
time_cost: 3
memory_cost: 10

When I'm trying to access the email at the `UserAuthenticator.php` file I get null. Sharing that code too:

```
class UserAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'user_login';

private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
{
    $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
}

public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
{
    $email = $request->request->get('username', '');
    var_dump($email); //gives string(0)
    exit;

    $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $email);

    return new Passport(
        new UserBadge($email),
        new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
        [
            new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->request->get('_csrf_token')),
        ]
    );
}`
```

Here I think I should share the VueJS code too.

```html
axios.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
        axios({
          method: "POST",
          url: "/api/login",
          data: {
            username: this.email,
            password: this.password,
          },
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }).then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        });
```

I should also inform that I tried with the following security.yaml but no luck

`

providers:
user_provider:
entity:
class: App\Entity\User
property: email
admin_provider:
entity:
class: App\Entity\Admin
property: email

firewalls:
dev:
pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
security: false

```
    main:
        lazy: true
        json_login:
            provider: user_provider
            check_path: user_login
        entry_point: App\Security\UserAuthenticator
        custom_authenticator:
            - App\Security\UserAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: user_logout
            target: /api/login

    admin_secured_area:
        pattern:   ^/admin
        provider: admin_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: /admin/login
            check_path: /admin/login_check
            default_target_path: /admin/login
            username_parameter: email
            password_parameter: password
        entry_point: App\Security\AdminAuthenticator
        custom_authenticator:
            - App\Security\AdminAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: admin_logout
            target: /admin/login
```

rest are same as above`

But no luck
`

Comment: are you sure 'this.email' in the ajax call is not empty ?

Comment: Yes, I've checked it through the inspector and found in the playload it's carrying the credentials properly.

Comment: You should implement onAuthenticationSuccess function and your class should extend Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractAuthenticator